# mongo shell: how can I return a date stored in ms formated in a readable form?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongo-shell

I have a mongoDB with dates stored as ms.

when I query the DB with:

```
> db.drives.find({deviceID:4},{driveDate:1})
```

I get

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52725be3a3d27f8c9eee4022"), "driveDate" : 1383226033496 }
```

I want to display this date within the result in the mongoshell in a readable format. Is there a way to 'convert the date on the fly', so that the result will look like this?:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52725be3a3d27f8c9eee4022"), "driveDate" : 'Thu Oct 31 2013 07:27:13 GMT-0600 (CST)' }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB shell you can use this:

```
db.drives.find({deviceID:4},{driveDate:1}).forEach(function (doc) {
  doc["driveDate"] = new Date(doc["driveDate"])
  printjson(doc)
});
```

Comment: You can use `new Date(doc.driveDate).toGMTString();` to get result closer to expected.